# Group the documents and also populate the fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a collection like:

```
MsgSchema = {
    user: { type: ObjectID, ref: 'User' },
    userAdmin: { type: String, default: 'no' },
    body: { type: String },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
}
```

I want to get the `msg` data with `userAdmin` field `yes` and by populating the user field and grouping the data by user field, and then sort the data based on `Date`. I looked at aggregate but couldn't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: Sorting by date is too broad, do you want to sort by user that have one of his/her message the most recently created ?

Comment: I want the messages grouped by the user field and sorted by Date, from most recently created to the 20 messages before that for that particular user